# auto.arima() and manual search gives different p & q values

Tags: arima

[image]

Hello, I have a non-stationary time series (population data) with 66 observations. Attached png file contains the acf and pacf plot for differenced (d=2) series.
(1) From that I assumed p=1 & q=1 (ignoring the higher lag significance, is it ok to ignore significant higher (>4 or >5) lags?).
(2) auto.arima() produced p=1 & q=0.
But none of them met the assumptions of White noise & normality. So I manually searched for p and q, and found p=4, q=2 follows all the assumptions. the output is as follows. Though AR(2) & AR(3) coefficients are not significant [image]

So I am little confused. I can't accept the models that don't follow the underlying assumptions in anyway. 
On other hand, Accepting a model which meets the assumption increases the order p greatly (having a higher order p is kind of unusual).

NB. No log/power transformation worked well (i.e. to meet assumptions at a reduced p & q value).

Any suggestions?

Comment: According to its documentation, auto.arima "returns best ARIMA model according to either AIC, AICc or BIC value."  It does not consider white noise or normality tests.

Comment: What tests did you run?  What were the results?  What is the frequency of the data (might you expect a p=4 term due to seasonality)?  What is the goal of the analysis--prediction? inference?  Is the AICc (for example) of your model all that different from the auto-selected model?  These are all things that should be considered in deciding between the two models.

Comment: It is a yearly data which contains yearly population count for last 66 years. 
I used QQ plot & Shapiro Wilk test to assess the normality assumption and residual ACF plot+Box-Ljung test to assess the white noise assumption. 
The model auto.arima() supplied does not follow these assumption anything nearer.
But the manually selected model meets the assumptions. Its AIC is also lower than auto.arima(). It is the lowest order (p+q) model which meets the assumptions.
My ultimate goal is forecast.

Comment: And another thing to add, as the model is (4,2,2): AR(2) & AR(3) coefficient's p-value>0.05. AR(1),AR(4),MA(1),MA(2) coefficients are significant.